# For loop for an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

If I want to print out the contents from the 13 element till the second last element of an array and I don't know how long the array is, is this how it would be done with BASH?

```
for array_element in `seq 13 $(({myarray[@]-1))`
do
   echo ${myarray[array_element]}
done
```

Comment: No closing brace on this `$(({myarray[@]-1))`

Comment: This is one valid way of it. Just change `$(({myarray[@]-1))` to `$((${#myarray[@]}-1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `bash`, don't use `seq`. Instead, use a C-style for loop.

```
for ((i=13; i < ${#myarray[@]} - 1; i++)); do
    echo ${myarray[i]}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
    for array_element in `seq $((${#myarray[@]}-1))`
    do
       echo ${myarray[$((array_element-1))]}
    done
```